# How To Prevent Image Hotlinking With Bucket Policy AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, hotlinking

I'm trying to prevent hotlinking of images in my S3 bucket. I thought bucket policy this would work but so far no luck:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Bucket policy for example.com",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow GET requests referred by example.com",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://www.example.com/*",
                        "http://www.example.com/*",
                        "https://example.com/*",
                        "http://example.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow GET requests that don't specify a referrer",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:Referer": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I make it so this policy denies access to images embedded on other websites?

Comment: My individual permissions is set to, everyone: read access - could that be the issue?

Comment: With public files set, there may be nothing to deny anything. Try changing from "Allow" to "Deny" in your policy and from "StringLike" to "StringNotLike".

Comment: Yep just figured that out :D